Docker: server unexpectedly closed connection
I have a celery worker inside docker, when doing a task that takes 10 minutes, it won't be able to send results as it will lose connection with the rabbitmq server.
if the task is done without docker it will be working fine.
rabbitmq is in a docker as well and they both on separate servers.
rabbitmq logs says missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
if the task is just time.sleep it will work fine but if it's something like the following:
from celery_project import app
import time
import logging


@app.task(queue="test_load_balancer_q", acks_late=True)
def test_task():
    start_time = time.time()
    duration = 600  # 10 minutes in seconds
    
    # Simulating a task by doing continuous work until 10 minutes have passed
    while (time.time() - start_time) < duration:
        # Perform some non-trivial work (e.g., calculations)
        _ = sum(i**2 for i in range(10000))

    logging.info("Task completed after 10 minutes")

it will fail, any ideas?
